# Why does this code that reads from cin recurse infinitely if the user types an invalid value?

Tags: c++, cin

I am learning C++, and I wrote this code:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace input
{
  template <typename T>
  T prompt_user(std::string prompt)
  {
    T input;
    std::cout << prompt << ": ";
    std::cin >> input;
    if (std::cin.fail())
    {
      std::cin.clear();
      prompt_user<T>(prompt);
    }
    return input;
  }
} // namespace input
```

If the user types in an invalid value, my `if` statement would catch it **with std::cin.fail()** (I think that's how you do it) and start over. But it instead loops my code infinitely and skips `cin`. How can I fix this?

Comment: `If the user types in an invalid value,` Where do you read that invalid value? If you don't read it, it's going to be read again.

Comment: Why have you written this as a recursive function?  A loop is the obvious choice.

Comment: This was a dumb question. I should probably rewrite this with a while true loop. I just thought that it made sense to go to the beginning of the function to redo the process?

Comment: BTW, if your code enters the fail loop, you don't do anything with the return value from calling the function (again).

Comment: @AnthonyL this is nowhere near dumb. On a given day we see thousands of questions that are pleas to do someone's homework for them, requests to find the bug in two-or-three lines of completely context-free code, appeals to help improve the performance of a program that doesn't even work, and the ever popular "Why doesn't `++i++` give the expected result?"

Comment: Side note: Avoid reusing identifiers in related scopes. You have `namespace input` and inside it `T input`. Compiler's OK with it, but it might screw with the heads of your fellow programmer's and will mess up plaintext searches. Few things more annoying than grepping for where a variable is used while bug hunting and finding dozens of lines of output for unrelated hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>, '\n')` below `std::cin.clear()`. I am so sorry for my mess up.

Answer (score 2):

When you start over, you just read the same invalid value again. You have no code to figure out where the invalid value begins and ends in the input stream and remove it.

It's not clear what the fix is. What the invalid value consists of may depend on the type. Do you want to discard a line? Do you want to discard characters until you find valid input? Or what?

You need to decide what behavior you want and code it.